# How to add new namespace in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, namespaces

I am creating `MVC` project behind I am using C# code. I have

```
`CloudConfigurationManager`
```

in using read  db value . Its  showing red Error . I have searched google I need to add  namespace. 
`using Microsoft.Azure;`

I  have added that also  but again Getting Error Like this

```
type or namespace 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace  'microsoft' (are you missing  an assembly reference?)  showing like this  how to fix this issue how can I add namespace Azure?
```

Comment: Did you even read the error?  "(are you missing  an assembly reference?)" is pretty clear.  Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: Do you have a reference with the name "Microsoft.Azure" when you expand your project references?

Comment: Do you know how to use nuget? If you don't, learn. Install the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager package to solve your issue. Whatever tutorial or guide you're following should have told you that already.

Comment: thank you @J.Steen i fixed my issues

Answer (score 2):

You need reference to the `Microsoft.Azure`. Follow below steps to add reference.

1. In Solution Explorer, right click on project and click add reference.
2. In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
3. Select the `Microsoft.Azure` and then click OK.

**EDIT :**

Also as per J Steen's comment you can add it using nuget package manager. Use below command in `Package Manager Console`.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
```

Comment: This is C#, not VB.NET.  That's not how you add a reference.

Comment: @DavidH. -- It is now that he's edited it, yes.  That's why I removed my down vote.

Answer (score 2):

i have Fixed issues select Tools Menu  select  NuGet package Manger console and select  package manger  console and install   `Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager`  after fixed issues